# extract value from array on condition

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Hi i have a table like this :

```
+-----------------+------------------+
|           id    |  dates           | 
+------------------------------------+
|  1              |{2010,2011,2018}  |                    
|  2              |      2000        |                       
+------------------------------------+
```

and i d like to test for each row if there is a date < 2015 if it is the case it should return the closest value.

for this case it should return for id 1 : 2011 and for id 2 : null

EDIT this is the solution :

```
case when (select max (x) FROM unnest(ARRAY[c.dates]) as x)< 2015 then (select max (x) FROM unnest(ARRAY[c.dates]) as x)
        else null end as "15com",
```

Comment: Please give more detail about the data types you’re dealing with, sample input and expected output

Comment: the data type is year converted to int . I need to extract the last year of activity before 2015 and if there is no value in array smaller then it return null

Comment: What would  case when 2015 > any{2000,2010,,2017} then ???

Comment: 2010 (it should take the closest value)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "array"? And why is the word "array" involved with your problem? Is it that you want the largest year less than 2015, and if none is found 2020? Or is it that some years are special? If so, how are they special?

Comment: if there is no value lesser than 2015 then null

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when array[2015] > array[2000,2017] then 2000 end
```